# "lvalue required as left operand of assignment if(comp1<=comp2 && acum=1)

Tags: javascript

The following code produces a "lvalue required as left operand of assignment  `if (comp1 <= comp2 && acum = 1)`

I assume I'm writing this wrong, what is wrong? and how would I write it correctly?

Comment: You want `==`, the equality operator. `=` is the assignment operator.  So, `if(comp1 <= comp2 && acum == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Going back to what Villa7 said, The boolean equalty operator is 2 equal signs(==) not 1(=). This should fix your problem.